# How to make a http request directly in jsx "src"

Tags: reactjs, http, jsx

I have a list o elements in react and for everyoane i want to make a GET request in order to receive an image.

I've tried to make an asynch method which calls the GET endpoint. The request worked but image didn't showed up.

Also, i've tried to make the request directly in src  JSX code. Same problem

```
src={getLessonPicture(lesson.lesson.name)}
```

```
export function getLessonPicture(lessonName) {
    return request({
        url: API_BASE_URL + "/downloadLessonPhoto/" + lessonName,
        method: 'GET'
    });
}
```

```
    async getPhoto(name){

        let image;

        getLessonPicture(name)
            .then(response  => {
                this.image = response;

            });

        await this.sleep(2000);

        return this.image;
        // return image;
    }
```

Can you make me understand where i am wrong.
Thanck you

Comment: is it the image itself or the image url you want from AJAX?

Answer (score 0):

I assume the `request` in the `getLessonPicture` function returns a `Promise`. You cannot set the `src` attribute on a image to a promise. You have either `await` the Promise or use a `.then` callback, and then set the `src` attribute to the value you get.

I think that is what you tried doing in your `getPhoto` method, however you should really use `this.setState` to update state, and not put properties directly on an instance (like `this.image = response`).

You haven't shared your entire component, but maybe something like this would work:

```js
function getLessonPicture(lessonName) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve('https://unsplash.it/200/200'), 1000);
  });
}

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      image: '',
    };
  }
  
  componentDidMount() {
    getLessonPicture().then((image) => {
      console.log(image);
      this.setState({ image });
    });
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Hello, World</h1>
        <img src={this.state.image } />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<MyComponent />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```